# Moving all {'s to the right of function name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm merging some code and this code's functions are all like this:

```
void someFunction()
{

}
```

While all our code needs to be:

```
   void someFunction() {

    }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to find and replace in order to change everything at once. It would save me hours of work.

I'm using VS 2008.

Thanks

Comment: Are you having trouble merging the code or do you just want to make all your code look funny? (Guidelines state you should have the beginning braces on their own line -- helps with readability.) You might be able to change the formatting rules in VS2008 and reformat either the old code or your code, and then re-attempt the merge.

Comment: @Cory: Which guidelines? I'm not aware of any universal guidelines handed down from the programming gods. You mean *your* guidelines? That's nice; people have different conventions, though.

Comment: One thing to watch for: if I write a function like this: `void MyFunction() // Here's what this does` and then put a brace on the next line, pulling the brace up a line might accidentally comment it out.  Any solution should watch for this case.

Comment: related [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2801919#2801919).

Comment: Slow day at the office? Or are you just looking for a way to procrastinate by doing meaningless work?

Comment: I have to say; this is the dumbest thing ever (not you, whomever is making you do this). The rule ought to be: "In new code, do it this way and whenever you work on old code, fix it then." It is _stupid_ to waste time "fixing" perfectly working code in such a way that doesn't make a bit if difference semantically. Unless your company is just out of clients to pay money to get actual work done, I see no need to do this. How many times have you had to do this type of work before?

Comment: @ San Jacinto once before, and it was long and tedious, and so that is why I want to find a better way. Yes I know it's silly but what can you do...

Comment: If you use C# you should purchase resharper

Comment: @GMan: Whoa, didn't mean to stir the pot there. I take it back! Also, I agree with San Jacinto.

Comment: Use a real editor (like vi) it can auto format the code for you.

Comment: @Cory: A mild stir. :) I personally find a brace on its own line much easier to read, but we should be careful not to assume that's a fact.

Comment: @San - don't be ridiculous?  If it wasn't for extremely time consuming changes that affect nothing we'd have to do real work, and that takes care and thought!  WTF do you expect of us???  We've got a great thing here, act like we're busy doing something when we're actually doing nothing at all and here you are trying to ruin it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio's Replace All on the Find and Replace window, with regular expressions. Going to be something like
Find: `\):b*\n:b*\{`
Replace: `) {`
You'll want to try it out a bit first to make sure it doesn't change things you don't want changed, like if you want to keep your `if() {` on separate lines.
Another option which might work is to get all your visual studio text options the way you want them and then try to auto-format each file.

Comment: It gives "Syntax error in pattern", but you're on the right lines (I've been trying to get it right myself).

Comment: Thanks. Forgot the \'s in front of the ) and {. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

There's an excellent open source code reformatter called [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) that's designed for exactly this purpose. Configure it with the style settings that you want followed, and it just works. Highly recommended.

> Artistic Style is a source code
>   indenter, formatter, and beautifier
>   for the C, C++, C# and Java
>   programming languages.
>
> When indenting source code, we as
>   programmers have a tendency to use
>   both spaces and tab characters to
>   create the wanted indentation.
>   Moreover, some editors by default
>   insert spaces instead of tabs when
>   pressing the tab key, and other
>   editors (Emacs for example) have the
>   ability to "pretty up" lines by
>   automatically setting up the white
>   space before the code on the line,
>   possibly inserting spaces in a code
>   that up to now used only tabs for
>   indentation.
>
> Since the NUMBER of space characters
>   showed on screen for each tab
>   character in the source code changes
>   between editors (unless the user sets
>   up the number to his liking...), one
>   of the standard problems programmers
>   are facing when moving from one editor
>   to another is that code containing
>   both spaces and tabs that was up to
>   now perfectly indented, suddenly
>   becomes a mess to look at when
>   changing to another editor. Even if
>   you as a programmer take care to ONLY
>   use spaces or tabs, looking at other
>   people's source code can still be
>   problematic.
>
> To address this problem, Artistic
>   Style was created - a filter written
>   in C++ that automatically re-indents
>   and re-formats C / C++ / C# / Java
>   source files. It can be used from a
>   command line, or it can be
>   incorporated as classes in another C++
>   program.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT and IDEs usually have formatting rules you can define and then apply to whole files with a single click in menu or keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Under

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C++ >
>   Formatting > New Lines,

you should be able to change the rules (temporarily), reformat your code, and then attempt the merge. (I pulled those settings from C# -- I don't have C++ stuff installed on this machine to verify.)